# NLP: Sentence segmentation by intent

Tags: nlp

I am trying to find a solution for sentence segregation by intent. As one sentence may have multiple intents, I would like to separate a piece of text into short sentences by intents.

**For example: To separate 'Email my team meeting is today, and attach the schedule file' into 'Email my team meeting is today', 'and attach the schedule file'. OR 'I want apple and orange and I will be late tonight' into 'I want apple and orange', 'and I will be late tonight'.**

I've checked chunking and sentence tokenizing, I think chunking might be a starting point but it does not give a close approach. Can someone give me some suggestion? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is the sentence segmentation for you the main goal or is it only a tool to serve some higher goal? I think there are other, maybe easier solutions, to capture multiple intents in a sentence - if that is the goal.

Comment: To Bau: Yes, eventually to capture multiple intents is our final goal. However my team decide to break it down first and this is our first try. If you can suggest an alternative approach it would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, I would interpret your problem as a multilabel classification problem which might be (at least from what I have done in the past) easier than first trying to segment the sentences. Each sentence can have multiple labels, such as "User wants fruits" and "User will be late".

You can tackle this by implementing a [One-Vs-Rest classifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html#sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier). This will train a classifier for each label, but the labels are not mutually exclusive. This basically means each label will have its own classifier trained and each one, given a sentence, will decide if its label is appropriate or not. If two labels are appropriate, then two labels are assigned.

From my experience, if you vectorize with a simple TFIDF and some simple preprocessing before and then use some classic classifier you can already get quite good results if you have good training data.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! However, the fact is, we are short at training/test data and we do have a existing black box API that can detect sentence intent for us. So under such case, we are trying to break the sentence down and fed them into the API one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Sentence segmentation is the solution I would go for, assuming you having the training data separated for each intent, you could train a sentence segmenter (sequence tagging model) on synthetically generated data by simply augmenting utterances from each intent.

For example, assuming we have 4 intents with multiple training utterances, you could generate a training text for the sentence segmenter by randomly selecting a sentences number "s_num" which represents how many intents/sentences that will be included in this training utterance, then according to this number randomly pick a "s_num" number of sentences and append them together making a training instance for the segmenter.

The labels could be as follows:

"This is an intent1 sentence and this is an intent2 sentence"
["Start", "O", "O", "O", "END", "O", "Start", "O", "O", "O", "END"]